# Terminating Facebook Session for node.js using fbgraph

Tags: facebook, node.js, fb-graph

I am creating an app, which uses facebook authorization. I am using the fbgraph api, suggested on the facebook api pages. However, I am currently unable to figure out a way to end the session for facebook using the api.

Comment: FB.logout()- Log the user out of your site and Facebook ! https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

Comment: thanks. I was using the wrong third-party library for facebook. node.js extensions for facebook aren't that well documented, and lead to only more confusion. Using the Javascript the older way is a much better option. Thanks.